# Command to force open (clientside) Safari browser on iOS device?

Tags: ios, mobile

We are working on a mobile webpage, and on iOS devices we would like to force to open the Safari browser (no tab, but force open Safari browser). Which command line do we need to use?

so an iPhone user klicks on this link and Safari browser will open and will open this specific URL?

Comment: u guys working on iPhone application?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide some more details on your scenario, If you want to open safari browser from your iOS application used following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your specific url"]];
```

Or your code is in HTML5, javascript and css, handle webView's delegate method `shouldStartLoadWithRequest` like this:

```
#pragma mark UIWebView
#pragma mark UIWebViewDelegate

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

     // Handle request url to open safari browser for your specific url
    if([[[request URL] absoluteString] isEqualToString:@"Your specific url"]){

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];

        return NO;
    }
  return YES;
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be URLWithString ?

Comment: Sorry Guys, it is not an application. We are takling about a mobile webpage.

Scenario:

Comment: Sorry Guys, it is not an application. We are takling about a mobile webpage.
Scenario:
user select our Guest WiFi and the iOS device is opening this OS window to show the webpage where the Guest has to accept the Terms for Guestnetwork (hotspot login). By clicking on accept Button, the Client device will be accepted in the network and will be redirected to our Homepage.

Here is the problem, why would we force an iOS device to open a Safari Window when the Guest accept terms..
the dedicated iOS Login WiFi Window is closing automatically when the Client is accepted on network (internet access).

Answer (score 0):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"<URL>"]];` should do the trick for you if its from within an app that you want to launch safari. If its a link inside say a UIWebView, you will need to handle the link click in the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to do the same openURL stuff.

Comment: Sorry Guys, it is not an application. We are takling about a mobile webpage.
Scenario:
user select our Guest WiFi and the iOS device is opening this OS window to show the webpage where the Guest has to accept the Terms for Guestnetwork (hotspot login). By clicking on accept Button, the Client device will be accepted in the network and will be redirected to our Homepage.

Here is the problem, why would we force an iOS device to open a Safari Window when the Guest accept terms..
the dedicated iOS Login WiFi Window is closing automatically when the Client is accepted on network (internet access).